# Histogram with uneven heights within bins

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why does my histogram look like this? I'm plotting it using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 25)
plt.show()
```

where `data` contains about 500,000 sorted points. Shouldn't each bin be smooth at the top?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your data might not be a flat list, but, e.g., a list of lists or similarly structured. In that case, `hist` will bin by sublist. This script demonstrates the difference:

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [[random.randint(0, x) for x in range(20)] for y in range(100)]

plt.subplot(211)
# structured
plt.hist(data, 25)

plt.subplot(212)
# flattened
plt.hist([i for l in data for i in l], 25)

plt.show()
```

You will probably have to use some kind of similar "flattening" on your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this example from the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html) displays the kind of plot you want. Therefore, you should either use `histtype="stepfilled"` or `histtype="bar"`.